# Deleting an image from android device?

Tags: android, android-studio, delete-file, android-gallery

I want to delete an image that user selects through

> ACTION_GET_CONTENT

I am successfully able to select image and show it in recycleview,
I am selecting image like this:

```
switch (requestCode) {
        case 42:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();

                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = getBaseContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                    int maxHeight = 1920;
                    int maxWidth = 1920;

                    float scale = Math.min(((float) maxHeight / bm.getWidth()), ((float) maxWidth / bm.getHeight()));

                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale);

                    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);

                    saveImageToInternalStorage(bitmap, getFileName(uri));
                    bm.recycle();
                    bitmap.recycle();

                    finishActivity(42);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
```

Now I want to delete this image from users gallery but it should still be visible in the recyclerview

I get the photoPath as

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A5793
```

Comment: just do something like `File.delete(uri.getPath())` it will delete actual file

Comment: Where do i write this?

Comment: @StuckWithAndroid before `finishActivity()`

Comment: you need to refresh gallery after deleting anything, or else you can verify it by visiting `file manager` not the `gallery`.

Comment: `but it should still be visible in the recyclerview` There is nothing in your code that made an image visible in a recycle view.

Comment: @blackapps you must go through https://stackoverflow.com/conduct.

Comment: i am not able to delete it @Blu

Comment: can you edit post like how do you get your `photoPath`

Comment: you must get the absolute path to delete your file, maybe thats what going on wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
File file = new File(photoPath);
file.delete();
```

Comment: you can give the uri there

Comment: but i am not able to get a proper uri

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it will work for you

```
switch (requestCode) {
    case 42:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = getBaseContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                int maxHeight = 1920;
                int maxWidth = 1920;

                float scale = Math.min(((float) maxHeight / bm.getWidth()), ((float) maxWidth / bm.getHeight()));

                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postScale(scale, scale);

                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);

                saveImageToInternalStorage(bitmap, getFileName(uri));
                bm.recycle();
                bitmap.recycle();

                File file = new File(convertMediaUriToPath(uri)); // it will get the absolute path of your file from your URI
                if (file.delete()) // it will delete your actual file from storage, but not from any holder you placed it.
                     //Make a Toast that file is successfully deleted
                 else
                     //Make a Toast that file is not deleted
                finishActivity(42);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Method to get `Absolute PATH`

```
public String convertMediaUriToPath(Uri uri) {
    String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, proj,  null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(column_index); 
    cursor.close();
    return path;
}
```

Hope it will work for you:)
Let me know if its working or not.

Comment: I couldn't figure it out, as it makes my device unresponsive

Answer (score -1):

If you want to delete the image the user selected with ACTION_GET_CONTENT:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();

DocumentFile docfile = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(context, uri);

docfile.delete();
```

Comment: Commenting that it does not work does not bring you further. You will have an exception or so. Please tell. Put this code in onActivityResult and see that the file gets deleted. Remove all other code from onActivityResult to test.

Comment: Ha ha. `StuckWithDoesNotWork`.